# Uploading a file via android app to PHP web server

Tags: php, android, rest, upload

An independent developer is developing a native Android app for me. I am responsible for making the API endpoint in PHP for the app to upload an image file to the server.

I do not have any Android development experience (so I can't answer any questions you may have in this regard). All uploads I have done before in PHP were on-site, using a browse button, and then I have access to the `$_FILES` object, easy-peasy, but I am not sure what the inputs from the app will be (developer is not available right now). How does this ***typically*** work when an app sends uploaded file data through to an API endpoint? Is it an encoded string of sorts? I am assuming that the app will read the file from the local device, and pass a string through to me, that I need to handle via something like `file_put_contents` on the server. Is that correct?

Edit: I simulated this in Postman to some degree. I set up the endpoint to simply output `$_FILES` in PHP, and then browsed for a file in Postman to send, and Postman uses `new CURLFILE()` to pass the file on to the API endpoint. It then appears that I have access to the `$_FILES` object. So - let me rephrase the question slightly now: Is it safe to assume I will get the file in that format and handle as a normal upload, or what should I prepare for?

Comment: The app should aim to send the HTTP request in exactly the same way a browser would, so that you don't need to change the PHP code at all. There's no reason why it can't. It should be a standard multipart HTTP request. You should not need to modify your backend to suit each different front-end...that would be a fundamental design mistake.

Comment: Thank you, @ADyson. I can confirm this works with a postman simulation. Please post your comment as the answer, and I will accept it. Thank you!